# How to include a policy json file in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Downloaded this iam policy file and save it in the root path besides main.tf in Terraform:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2.1/docs/install/iam_policy.json

Made this creation want to call the policy file

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "worker_policy" {
  name   = "worker-policy"
  policy = file("iam-policy.json")
}
```

The `tflint` got this error:

```
15:36:27 server.go:418: rpc: gob error encoding body: gob: type not registered for interface: tfdiags.diagnosticsAsError
Failed to check ruleset. An error occurred:

Error: Failed to check `aws_iam_policy_invalid_policy` rule: reading body EOF
```

I also tried this way, the same result:

```
policy = jsondecode(file("iam-policy.json"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the latest version of `tflint`?

Because I've tried and everything was OK for me

There were my steps:

**NOTE**: `tflint v0.31.0` and `terraform v1.0.2`

[1] `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2.1/docs/install/iam_policy.json`

[2] In my `main.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "worker_policy" {
  name   = "worker-policy"
  policy = file("iam_policy.json")
}
```

[3] Run `terraform plan`

[4] Have gotten

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_iam_policy.worker_policy will be created   + resource "aws_iam_policy" "worker_policy" {
      + arn       = (known after apply)
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = "worker-policy"
      + path      = "/"
      + policy    = jsonencode(
            {
              + Statement = [
                  + {
                      + Action   = [
                          + "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                          + "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                          + "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
...
```

[5] Run `tflint`

```
~/Work/Other/test ❯ tflint --init

Plugin `aws` is already installed                                                                                                                                             

~/Work/Other/test ❯ tflint

~/Work/Other/test ❯
```

Comment: I add `policy = file("${path.module}/iam-policy.json")`, it works.